# Fav icon is not displayed when download a pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, favicons

I set the favicon icon in admin panel. When downloading a file fav icon is not displayed instead default magento icon displaying. I have changed the default magento favicon icon in this path `htdocs/media/favicon/default`, but it would't help. I put my favicon in the following directory

1. Root directory
2. media/favicon/default
3. skin/frontend/default/default But still that magento icon is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Put the favicon in your Magento root directory.

Comment: Thanks. Already I put my favicon in root directory but it wound't reflect. Is there any other way to display my favicon.

Comment: It's very strange. Have you tried browsing with incognito mode?

Comment: No. I am not tried with  incognito mode.

Comment: Try now (crossed fingers)

Comment: No change,  magento  favicon is still displaying.

Comment: I put my favicon in the following directory
1)root directory,
2)media/favicon/default,
3)skin/frontend/default/default
But still that magento icon is displayed.

Comment: @Rasheed, Did you find a way to show favicon.ico in pdf files?